# How to solve this system of equations in functions $f(y)$ and $g(y)$?

Tags: proof-verification, systems-of-equations

> How to solve the following system of simultaneous equations for $f(y)$ and $g(y)$?
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> y^4 &= f(y) + y^2 g \left( y^2 \right), \tag{1} \newline
> y^2 &= -2y f^\prime (y) + f(y) - y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right). \tag{2}
> \end{align}
> $$

My Attempt:

> Upon differentiating both the sides of the first equation w.r.t $y$, we obtain
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> y^4 &= f(y) + y^2 g \left( y^2 \right), \tag{1} \newline
> y^2 &= -2y f^\prime (y) + f(y) - y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right),  \tag{2} \newline
> 4y^3 &= f^\prime(y) + 2y g\left( y^2 \right) + 2y^3 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right). \tag{3} 
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Now multiplying (3) by $\frac{y}{2}$ we get
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> y^4 &= f(y) + y^2 g \left( y^2 \right), \tag{1} \newline
> y^2 &= -2y f^\prime (y) + f(y) - y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right),  \tag{2} \newline
> 4y^3 &= f^\prime(y) + 2y g\left( y^2 \right) + 2y^3 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{3} \newline
> 2y^4 &= \frac{y}{2}f^\prime(y)  + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right) + y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right). \tag{4}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Now adding (2) to (4) we get
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> y^4 &= f(y) + y^2 g \left( y^2 \right), \tag{1} \newline
> y^2 &= -2y f^\prime (y) + f(y) - y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right),  \tag{2} \newline
> 4y^3 &= f^\prime(y) + 2y g\left( y^2 \right) + 2y^3 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{3} \newline
> 2y^4 &= \frac{y}{2}f^\prime(y)  + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right) + y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{4} \newline
> 2y^4 + y^2 &= - \frac{3y}{2} f^\prime(y) + f(y) + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right). \tag{5}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Now using (1) in (5) we obtain
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> y^4 &= f(y) + y^2 g \left( y^2 \right), \tag{1} \newline
> y^2 &= -2y f^\prime (y) + f(y) - y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right),  \tag{2} \newline
> 4y^3 &= f^\prime(y) + 2y g\left( y^2 \right) + 2y^3 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{3} \newline
> 2y^4 &= \frac{y}{2}f^\prime(y)  + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right) + y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{4} \newline
> 2y^4 + y^2 &= - \frac{3y}{2} f^\prime(y) + f(y) + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right), \tag{5} \newline
> 2y^4 + y^2 &= - \frac{3y}{2} f^\prime(y) + y^4. \tag{6}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> And, upon simplifying (6) we obtain
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> y^4 &= f(y) + y^2 g \left( y^2 \right), \tag{1} \newline
> y^2 &= -2y f^\prime (y) + f(y) - y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right),  \tag{2} \newline
> 4y^3 &= f^\prime(y) + 2y g\left( y^2 \right) + 2y^3 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{3} \newline
> 2y^4 &= \frac{y}{2}f^\prime(y)  + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right) + y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{4} \newline
> 2y^4 + y^2 &= - \frac{3y}{2} f^\prime(y) + f(y) + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right), \tag{5} \newline
> y^4 + y^2 &= - \frac{3y}{2} f^\prime(y). \tag{6}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Solving (6) for $f^\prime(y)$, we obtain
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> y^4 &= f(y) + y^2 g \left( y^2 \right), \tag{1} \newline
> y^2 &= -2y f^\prime (y) + f(y) - y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right),  \tag{2} \newline
> 4y^3 &= f^\prime(y) + 2y g\left( y^2 \right) + 2y^3 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{3} \newline
> 2y^4 &= \frac{y}{2}f^\prime(y)  + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right) + y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{4} \newline
> 2y^4 + y^2 &= - \frac{3y}{2} f^\prime(y) + f(y) + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right), \tag{5} \newline
> f^\prime(y) &= -\frac{2}{3} \left( y^3 + y \right). \tag{6}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Upon integrating (6) w.r.t to $y$, we get 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> y^4 &= f(y) + y^2 g \left( y^2 \right), \tag{1} \newline
> y^2 &= -2y f^\prime (y) + f(y) - y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right),  \tag{2} \newline
> 4y^3 &= f^\prime(y) + 2y g\left( y^2 \right) + 2y^3 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{3} \newline
> 2y^4 &= \frac{y}{2}f^\prime(y)  + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right) + y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{4} \newline
> 2y^4 + y^2 &= - \frac{3y}{2} f^\prime(y) + f(y) + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right), \tag{5} \newline
> f^\prime(y) &= -\frac{2}{3} \left( y^3 + y \right), \tag{6} \newline
> f(y) &= - \frac{y^4}{6} - \frac{y^2}{3} + c, \tag{7}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   where $c$ is a constant (independent of $y$).
>
> Substituting the value of $f(y)$ from (7) into (1) we obtain
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> y^4 &= - \frac{y^4}{6} - \frac{y^2}{3} + c + y^2 g \left( y^2 \right), \tag{1} \newline
> y^2 &= -2y f^\prime (y) + f(y) - y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right),  \tag{2} \newline
> 4y^3 &= f^\prime(y) + 2y g\left( y^2 \right) + 2y^3 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{3} \newline
> 2y^4 &= \frac{y}{2}f^\prime(y)  + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right) + y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{4} \newline
> 2y^4 + y^2 &= - \frac{3y}{2} f^\prime(y) + f(y) + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right), \tag{5} \newline
> f^\prime(y) &= -\frac{2}{3} \left( y^3 + y \right), \tag{6} \newline
> f(y) &= - \frac{y^4}{6} - \frac{y^2}{3} + c, \tag{7}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Solving (1) for $g\left( y^2 \right)$, we get
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> g \left( y^2 \right)  &=  \frac{7y^2}{6} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{c}{y^2} , \tag{1} \newline
> y^2 &= -2y f^\prime (y) + f(y) - y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right),  \tag{2} \newline
> 4y^3 &= f^\prime(y) + 2y g\left( y^2 \right) + 2y^3 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{3} \newline
> 2y^4 &= \frac{y}{2}f^\prime(y)  + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right) + y^4 g^\prime \left( y^2 \right), \tag{4} \newline
> 2y^4 + y^2 &= - \frac{3y}{2} f^\prime(y) + f(y) + y^2 g\left( y^2 \right), \tag{5} \newline
> f^\prime(y) &= -\frac{2}{3} \left( y^3 + y \right), \tag{6} \newline
> f(y) &= - \frac{y^4}{6} - \frac{y^2}{3} + c. \tag{7}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Finally, from (7) and (1) we get
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> f(y) &= - \frac{y^4}{6} - \frac{y^2}{3} + c, \newline 
> g\left(y^2 \right) &=  \frac{7y^2}{6} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{c}{y^2}, \newline 
> & \mbox{ and upon substituting $y$ for $y^2$ in the formula for $g(y^2)$ we get } \newline
> g(y) &= \frac{7y}{6} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{c}{y}. 
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Therefore our required solution is
>   $$ f(y) = - \frac{y^4}{6} - \frac{y^2}{3} + c,  \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad g(y) = \frac{7y}{6} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{c}{y}.  $$

Is my solution correct and accurate in each and every detail? If so, have I managed to end up with a correct pair of formulas for $f(y)$ and $g(y)$? If not, then where are the errors or issues?